# crypt para javascript

Tags: php, javascript, pdo

Bom estou trabalhando em um projeto que preciso utilizo o `crypt` como metodo para criptografar a senha, porém está senha preciso utilizar no mobile, como faço para usar algo que o `crypt` vai entender e que o web também vai ?

O que preciso é que qualquer local onde estiver ele consiga criptografar e descriptografar facilmente.

Uma outra duvida adjacente a esta é.

Suponhamos que criptografei a senha, e quero agora verificar fazer um teste para testificar que a senha está correta. Qual a maneira correta de fazer ? Abaixo o meu exemplo.

```
 $sql = "select USU.* from ( select COD_IDENT_IGREJ, COD_IDENT_PESSO, TXT_NOMEX_PESSO, TXT_FONEX_PESSO from tbl_PESSOAS where COD_IDENT_IGREJ = :COD_IDENT_IGREJ and TXT_EMAIL_PESSO = :TXT_EMAIL_PESSO and TXT_SENHA_USUAR = :TXT_SENHA_USUAR and FLG_STATU_PESSO = 'A' ) USU left join ( select COD_IDENT_IGREJ, FLG_STATU_IGREJ from tbl_IGREJA ) IGR on USU.COD_IDENT_IGREJ = IGR.COD_IDENT_IGREJ where IGR.FLG_STATU_IGREJ = 'A'";

    if (isset($this->params['email']) && isset($this->params['senha']) && isset($this->params['codIgreja'])) {
        $dataInput = array();
        $dataInput[':COD_IDENT_IGREJ'] = $this->params['codIgreja'];
        $dataInput[':TXT_EMAIL_PESSO'] = $this->params['email'];
        $dataInput[':TXT_SENHA_USUAR'] = crypt($this->params['senha']);
        $data = $this->conexao->fetchNaoRestritivo($sql, $dataInput);
```

Apos fazer isto verifico o `$data` para saber se existe ou não. Porém como andei lendo sobre o `crypt` a cada momento ele cria um algoritimo diferente para criptografar e descriptografar uma senha.

Nestes casos de PDO como verificar se a senha está correta ?

Comment: Não guarde senhas no mobile, nem encriptadas nem o hash delas. Guarde um token. Se a senha estiver lá, alguém em algum momento vai conseguir copiá-la para outro dispositivo.

Comment: Porém o nivel de informações em meu aplicativo não é elevado, as informações não necessariamente necessita de ter tanta segurança a este ponto